Name of a label that is clicked in Access VBA
I have many labels in the form and I want to do an activity after I click on the label such as changing the Capture of the label or the font color of the clicked labels being red, etc.
Is there a way that when clicking a label, the code will have the name of the label so that I can later write "Me.etc.ForeColor ="
something like Me.ActiveControl But there isn't Me.ActiveLabel
